# Параметр offset в VKApi

Tags: vkontakte-api

Объясните пожалуйста, зачем во многих методах VKApi есть параметр "offset", для чего он нужен. В документации сказано, что это для "сдвига", но как это понять?

P.S. Было бы хорошо с примерами для database.getCities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Параметр offset просто определяет "сдвиг".

Например если вы выбираете 1000 любых значений, и поставите offset=1000, то вы получите значения в диапазоне 1000-2000, тоесть другими словами offset это количество значений с начала списка, которые вы хотите упустить (типа говорите "прислать всё начиная с 10-й записи", где 10 и будет ваш offset)